# Craft CMS With Php/Nginx on Docker can't write outside Document Root

Tags: php, nginx, docker, content-management-system, docker-compose

I'm trying to set up a containerized version of a basic Craft CMS set up using Docker with Php and Nginx. Craft can't seem to write to folders outside of my Nginx Document Root. (See bottom of post for more details) I'm using Docker-Compose and this is my current Docker-compose.yml:

```
nginx:
   build: ./compose/nginx/
   ports:
     - 80:80
   links:
     - php
   volumes_from:
     - app

php:
   build: ./compose/php/
   expose:
     - 9000
   links:
     - mysql
   volumes_from:
     - app

app:
   image: php:7.0-fpm
   volumes:
     -   ./app:/var/www/html
     -   ./vendors:/var/www
   command: "true"

mysql:
   image: mysql:latest
   volumes_from:
     - data
environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    MYSQL_DATABASE: project
    MYSQL_USER: project
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: project

data:
   image: mysql:latest
   volumes:
     - /var/lib/mysql
   command: "true"

phpmyadmin:
   image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
   ports:
     - 8080:8080
   links:
     - mysql
   environment:
     PMA_HOST: mysql
```

This set up works perfectly, here are my two build files for Nginx
- DockerFile:

```
FROM nginx:latest

COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Default.conf

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Everything works near flawlessly, until I try to deploy Craft CMS, I understand that I don't have all the php-extensions, but I don't believe that affects my problem. I keep getting the Error, /var/www/craft/config isn't writable by PHP. Please fix that. Thus I am assuming that this is an error with permissions with Nginx and PHP. Although, I have tried opening a bash shell inside both of my nginx and php containers and chmod 777 craft/config folder, and I still get this error, thus I am a bit confused as to how to fix it.

EDIT 1 ------
 I was able to fix this problem by implementing the following into my Dockerfile within my php build profile.

```
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data
RUN usermod -G staff www-data
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

I'm not sure if this is the safest way.

Comment: Could it be something to do with SELinux permissions?

Comment: I don't believe that I have SELinux installed at all.

Answer (score -1):

In your *docker-compose.yml* **app** container definition the volume declaration **./vendors:/var/www** effectively overwrites **./app:/var/www/html**. */var/www/craft/* therefore very likely does not exist.
Volume declarations for **app** should look as follows instead:

```
app:
   image: php:7.0-fpm
   volumes:
     -   ./app:/var/www/html
     -   ./vendors:/var/www/vendors
   command: "true"
```

Comment: The volumes command doesn't overwrite anything existing there already. I logged into a bash in the container to double check and it does exist there. I was able to solve my problem, but I'm not sure if it is the safest/most effective way of doing it. See my edit 1.

Comment: Ah, gotchya. This was the best theory I had though.